# How to filter a UL, then search in the new UL

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create filters to search a list, then you can search within the filtered list. I have tabs that act as the filters, but I can't figure out how to limit the search function to whichever filter is clicked. Is there a way to check if a tab is clicked or a function is called in JavaScript?

Here is my general search function:

```
function searchTags() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById('inputTag');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("ulResources");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the filter function for one of my tabs(They are all the same, but input is changed to fit whatever the filter is):

```
    function searchMember() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = "member";
        filter = input.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("ulResources");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the asp code to match the filter tab above:

```
<a id="liMember" href="#" onclick="searchMember();" data-toggle="tab">Member</a>
```

And I have a search bar that calls searchTags():

```
<input id="inputTag" type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="searchTags();" placeholder="Search for a tag...">
```

Comment: What tabs? How are you calling these filter functions? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just checked if display != none, and then printed the results. 
I was overthinking this.